# Insert the records of a dbf file into a table in MS Access database using Delphi

Tags: ms-access, delphi, insert, dbf

I am trying to insert the records of a dbf file into a table in a MS Access database that I have already created.

The dbf file's name is `tab1.dbf` and it has three columns: `cl1, cl2, cl3`.

The MS Access database name is `db1` and it has one table `tb2` with three columns: `cl1, cl2, cl3`.

I have connected Delphi to the MS Access database using `ADOConnection1`.

To insert the dbf file's records, I have to click in a Button1 with OpenDialog1

The code I use is this :

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var importdir,ipo : string;

begin
if form1.OpenDialog1.Execute then
begin
importdir:= extractfiledir(form1.OpenDialog1.FileName);
ipo:= form1.OpenDialog1.FileName ;
end;
form1.Edit1.Text:= importdir;
ADOConnection1.Execute('insert into tab2 SELECT * FROM [ database = '+ipo+' ].tab1'  );
end;
```

but when i execut the form1 i have this error message :
name of the file is incorrect

can you help me guys ?

Comment: Where is ADOConnection1 connected? Also first try with a hardcoded filename.

Comment: Don't use a form var (``form1``) inside a form class!

Comment: @DelphiCoder This is useless but doesn't really harm.

Comment: @fpiette: Yes, it does hurt. It introduces a restriction that the code only works if you're using a variable in scope named `form1`. What happens if you're not auto-creating the form but are creating it in code (`MyForm := TForm1.Create(nil);`)? The code breaks, or you end up accessing the wrong instance of the form. You know this - **never** refer to a specifc instance of the class within the class itself. If you need to access a member of that class, use `Self` instead. We try not to encourage bad practices here.

Comment: @KenWhite Do you really think that I ignore that? I doesn't hurt here in the code the user show, it is not the OP problem. I feel offended.

Comment: guys, the problem i have that i d'ont know how to export the data from .dbf file to MS access table

Comment: Basically you need two ADOConnection (One for DBF and one for Access). Two ADOQuery (One for DBF and one for Access) connected to the thwo ADOConnections. Then using the ADOQuery connected to the DBF file, you execute a SELECT query to get records from DBF and then loop thru all records and for each record you execute an INSERT using the second ADOQuery. Where are you stuck in that process?

Comment: fpiette; will that's Something to start with
how to do the " loop thru all records and for each record you execute an INSERT using the second ADOQuery"?

Comment: so i manage to put the the records of the dbf file into a dbgrid (connected with ADOQuery and adoconnection) so i am stuck on how to insert the records of the dbgrid into the ms access table ?

Comment: You don't need a DBGrid at all. Move field by field from the DBF ADOQuery to feed a parametrized SQL INSERT statement to the Access ADOQuery. As a first step, try to show all the DBF file (Well, you can limit to 10 records) into a simple TMemo.

Comment: @fpiette: You didn't say *It's bad practice but it's not the problem here.* What you wrote was *This is useless but doesn't really harm*, which can be interpreted (especially by a new user) to mean that it *never* causes harm and therefore is OK to do, which it is not. I even mentioned that I knew you were aware of this - I wasn't meaning to offend, just to avoid writing things that might be misunderstood by a new coder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here after is one simple solution. It simple because it assume the Access database structure is the same as the dBASE structure. You'll get started with this example that you'll adapt to your needs.

```
procedure TDbfToAccessWithAdoForm.DbfToAccessButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
var
    Fld       : Integer;
    FldValue  : Variant;
    InsertSQL : String;
begin
    ADOConnectionAccess.Connected := TRUE;
    ADOConnectionDbf.Connected    := TRUE;
    ADOQueryDbf.SQL.Text          := 'Select * from Clients';
    ADOQueryDbf.Open;

    // Build the parametrized INSERT statement
    InsertSQL := 'insert into Clients(';
    for Fld := 0 to ADOQueryDbf.FieldCount - 1 do
        InsertSQL := InsertSQL + ADOQueryDbf.Fields[Fld].FieldName + ',';
    // Remove extra coma
    Delete(InsertSQL, Length(InsertSQL), 1);
    InsertSQL := InsertSQL + ') values (';
    for Fld := 0 to ADOQueryDbf.FieldCount - 1 do
        InsertSQL := InsertSQL + ':' + ADOQueryDbf.Fields[Fld].FieldName + ',';
    // Remove extra coma
    Delete(InsertSQL, Length(InsertSQL), 1);
    InsertSQL := InsertSQL + ')';

    while not ADOQueryDbf.Eof do begin
        ADOQueryAccess.SQL.Text := InsertSQL;
        for Fld := 0 to ADOQueryDbf.FieldCount - 1 do begin
            FldValue := ADOQueryDbf.Fields[Fld].Value;
            // Here you can do whatever conversion is required
            if FldValue = Null then begin
                if ADOQueryDbf.FieldDefList[Fld].DataType = ftDateTime then
                    FldValue := 0      // My Access table doesn't like empty datetime
                else
                    FldValue := ' ';   // My Access table doesn't like empty string
            end;
            ADOQueryAccess.Parameters.ParamByName(ADOQueryDbf.Fields[Fld].FieldName).Value := FldValue;
        end;
        ADOQueryAccess.ExecSQL;
        ADOQueryDbf.Next;
    end;

    ADOQueryDbf.Close;
    ADOQueryAccess.Close;
end;
```

You should add error checking and try/finally or try/except. I let you do it as you do usually.